# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении перед "обратившись"?

Tags: пунктуация

Получить услугу можно обратившись в Центр госуслуг.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

***Получить** услУгу можно, // **обратившись** в Центр госуслУг.*

Деепричастный оборот обособляется, так как обозначает **действие,** но **не признак действия.**

**Время** действия, обозначенное в сказуемом и в деепричастии, **не одно и то же.** Если/когда обратитесь в Центр, то тогда получите.

Comment: Творческая мастерская, кому они мешают.

Answer (score 0):

*Получить услугу можно обратившись в Центр госуслуг* — смысл предложения в том, как именно можно получить услугу.

*Получить услугу можно, обратившись в Центр госуслуг* — смысл в том, что услугу можно получить, деепричастгый оборот имеет значение уточнения.

Читайте **[3-й пункт и примечание к 4-му](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)**. Два примера оттуда (в которых оборот используется в конце безличного предложения):

*Выучить иностранный язык можно, лишь постоянно занимаясь им*;

*Это упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках*.

При тесной связи не обособляем, если в обороте весь смысл. Если же смысл не в нем, а только в сказуемом, то обособляем.